# why is there a mailto in the from section?

Tags: outlook

I received an email forward from a client. It has the following header info:

```
From: Electronic Notification [mailto:aaaa@xxx.com]
Sent: Wednesday, September 03, 2014 4:01 AM
To: vvv171@xxx.com; BZStuff
Subject: Some Subject
```

I am trying to understand why there is a "mailto" in the from section of this email. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reply to a different email address that it was received from.